# How do I get stock html content

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

This is my code:

```
webURL = 'http://q.10jqka.com.cn/thshy/detail/field/199112/order/desc/page/5/ajax/3/code/881121'
response = requests.get(webURL, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

It returns below, I want to get the detail information, but I don't know how to get:

```html
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s.thsi.cn/js/chameleon/chameleon.min.1597108.js"></script> <script src="//s.thsi.cn/js/chameleon/chameleon.min.1597108.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href="http://q.10jqka.com.cn/thshy/detail/field/199112/order/desc/page/5/ajax/3/code/881121";
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Better use selenium

Comment: your code gives me HTML with stock data. But maybe it sends different HTML for different IP (world region) or when it recognizes that it is script (not real browser) or run you run it too often or too fast.

Answer (score 0):

The data is generated by javascript, so using requests doesn't show you the proper HTMl that is generated by it.

To do so, you need to re-create that HTTP request the javascript is doing to display the data.

### Code Example

```
import requests
import pandas

cookies = {
    'vvvv': '1',
    'v': 'AvwW3GeEj6b0hbthB_HLP5XWzZGt9aAfIpm049Z9COfKoZAH_gVwr3KphHIl',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

response = requests.get('http://q.10jqka.com.cn/thshy/detail/field/199112/order/desc/page/5/ajax/3/code/881121', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, verify=False)
df = pandas.read_html(response.text)
df[0]
```

### Output

```
序号  代码  名称  现价  涨跌幅(%)  涨跌  涨速(%)   换手(%)   量比  振幅(%)   成交额 流通股 流通市值    市盈率 加自选
0   81  2618    丹邦科技    9.63    -4.08   -0.41   0.00    2.54    0.77    4.68    1.37亿   5.48亿   52.76亿  --  NaN
1   82  603290  斯达半导    215.00  -4.10   -9.20   0.00    5.13    0.70    4.95    4.49亿   0.40亿   86.00亿  317.68  NaN
2   83  603936  博敏电子    14.68   -4.18   -0.64   -0.41   4.02    0.81    4.31    2.39亿   3.97亿   58.23亿  25.88   NaN
3   84  300346  南大光电    39.51   -4.20   -1.73   -0.15   4.61    0.55    4.75    6.90亿   3.70亿   146.04亿 115.25  NaN
4   85  2199    东晶电子    8.63    -4.22   -0.38   -0.12   3.37    0.55    4.66    0.72亿   2.43亿   21.01亿  --  NaN
5   86  300657  弘信电子    21.32   -4.22   -0.94   0.09    2.23    0.89    6.51    1.38亿   2.84亿   60.54亿  --  NaN
6   87  688138  清溢光电    31.70   -4.23   -1.40   0.00    5.89    0.60    5.20    1.22亿   0.63亿   20.12亿  127.27  NaN
7   88  2579    中京电子    15.02   -4.33   -0.68   0.07    4.70    1.36    8.92    2.58亿   3.53亿   53.08亿  76.18   NaN
8   89  600360  华微电子    9.20    -4.37   -0.42   -0.11   4.83    0.65    4.89    4.36亿   9.60亿   88.35亿  257.01  NaN
9   90  603005  晶方科技    80.16   -4.51   -3.79   -0.01   4.39    0.67    5.72    11.57亿  3.22亿   257.75亿 82.58   NaN
10  91  688126  沪硅产业    48.46   -4.81   -2.45   0.06    12.56   0.73    8.05    28.34亿  4.50亿   217.98亿 --  NaN
11  92  688019  安集科技    417.32  -4.83   -21.18  -0.16   2.60    0.80    5.16    3.33亿   0.30亿   124.71亿 235.21  NaN
12  93  688396  华润微 53.00   -5.91   -3.33   -0.04   8.29    0.79    6.60    10.76亿  2.37亿   125.68亿 79.94   NaN
13  94  600770  综艺股份    6.16    -5.95   -0.39   -0.16   4.06    0.88    7.33    3.34亿   13.00亿  80.08亿  57.54   NaN
14  95  300456  赛微电子    27.97   -6.42   -1.92   -0.07   3.61    1.13    4.65    3.53亿   3.43亿   95.80亿  653.69  NaN
15  96  300139  晓程科技    9.08    -7.06   -0.69   0.00    15.55   1.01    6.04    3.21亿   2.20亿   19.97亿  --  NaN
16  97  603933  睿能科技    15.13   -7.46   -1.22   0.00    7.40    1.54    13.76   2.41亿   2.01亿   30.45亿  976.29  NaN
17  98  300460  惠伦晶体    14.86   -7.59   -1.22   0.07    11.13   0.94    8.15    4.01亿   2.36亿   35.01亿  409.60  NaN
18  99  688286  敏芯股份    193.90  -16.24  -37.60  -0.56   42.54   0.54    16.41   10.68亿  0.12亿   23.53亿  413.49  NaN
```

### Explanation

If you inspect the page and go to network tools --> XHR and refresh the page to record all requests and resposnses to the browser. you'll see an AJAX request the very first request made, if you click any of the requests can you see a preview in the right hand side of the sreen. In this case the response has all the HTML. Recreating this HTTP request will give you the data you want. If you right click the request and copy CURL(bash) you can input this into curl.trillworks.com to convert it into a nice format.

You can play about with whether you need cookies or not, I haven't done too much with this, you definitely need cookies.

We're using `pandas.read_html()` method to parse the HTML table because it's much easier than trying to use something like beautifulsoup.